# Android : How to get the src of an imageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and when I click on it I would like to change the image, but only if this is a special image (the default one in fact).

My xml :

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/button1"
android:src="@drawable/imgdefault" />
```

And I have a listener on it :

```
public OnClickListener button1Listener = new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          if (button1.getDrawable().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgdefault))) {
               button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImg);
    }
}
```

But it seems that my "if" is never true. So I can I check if this is still my default image on the ImageButton ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, one that comes to my mind is:

```
Boolean clicked = new Boolean(false);
button1.setTag(clicked); // wasn't clicked
button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          if( ((Boolean)button1.getTag())==false ){
              button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImg);
              button1.setTag(new Boolean(true));
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but it seems that it is not possible to cast from Object to a boolean ?